# Smarty - Getting Posted / Session Variables

Tags: php, smarty

I'm working on an "In My Basket" Feature on a shopping site. 
I'm pairing it on productid. 
I've done a tamper data on the post when you add to basket. The variable that is getting posted is **productid**.

I've been using [This](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl) as a guide to output the productid variable. But I'm just not getting a response from the page at all.

The code I am using is `{$smarty.request.productid}`

The TPL file I am using is [HERE](http://dev.lceonline.co.uk/test/products_list.tpl) I am working on the < div class="inbasket"> which is line 69.

It seems to output with the SERVER_NAME example. But I need that equivalent PHP $_POST VAR.

Does anyone have any idea on what I need to do to pull through the productid and show it on screen, Then I can do an IF statement based on that.

Also worth noting I am using Version 2.6.20 of Smarty

Hoping someone can help me out with this. It appears that smarty is just not showing the session variables at all...

Comment: did you also try `{$smarty.post.productid}`? are you maybe overwriting the request somewhere? did you try to `var_dump()`the `$_REQUEST['productid']`?

Comment: I've tried the post, yeah. Just tried var_dump($_REQUEST['productid'] which is outputting "NULL" to my screen.

Comment: then its not smarty. without the rest of your code I can only guess that you either overwrite the $_REQUEST or $_POST array somewhere or never post the productid at all.

Comment: Was just thinking is it worth putting the TPL code up somewhere. Here it is : http://dev.lceonline.co.uk/test/products_list.tpl I am working on the <div class="inbasket"> - Line 69

Comment: I've tried a few things but still no joy. I suspect the $_REQUEST is being overwritten.

Comment: @StuBlackett let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3028/discussion-between-sascha-galley-and-stublackett)

Comment: Are you sure index of your variable in $_POST array is productid? Can you show us print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: php filter functions will help

Comment: @Zyava I'm using "Tamper Data" plugin for FireFox to catch the POST var's. See this screenshot : http://www.dev.lceonline.co.uk/test/tamper.jpg

Comment: Where Tamper Data plugin gets post data? I need see what php got in $_POST array.

Comment: Tamper Data gets the post variables from clicking "Add To Cart" on the page. I am unable to show the $_POST array due to the smarty issue. It just doesnt print session or post or get var's#

Answer (score 22):

Using {$smarty.request.productid} will only get values that were are in the $_POST array or the $_GET array.
For session vars you would simply use "session" as in {$smarty.session.productid}.  With smarty the same applies to

- $_POST  --  {$smarty.post.productid}
- $_GET --    {$smarty.get.productid}
- $_REQUEST -- {$smarty.request.productid} (request will get vars from both $_POST and $_GET)
- $_SESSION -- {$smarty.session.productid}

Put this at the top of your tpl file and it will popup with all assigned smarty vars

```
{debug}
```

Want to see what is in the session?  Put this at the top of you tpl file

```
{php}
print_r($_SESSION);
{/php}
```

Comment: Hi,

The {debug} is just showing "No templates included" and the {php}print_r($_SESSION);{/php} isnt showing either.

See this screen shot : http://www.dev.lceonline.co.uk/test/debug_screen.jpg

I'm starting to think its an X-Cart setup issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you fail to debug, You've another alternative to do.

In PHP file,

$smarty->assign('request_var',$_REQUEST['var1']);

In Smarty TPL,

Use {$request_var}

Answer (score 1):

BTW: When printing user input, always use the "escape" modifier. Otherwise your application is vulnerable (XSS etc).

`{$smarty.post.productid|escape}`